# NGINX redirect all domains in to one

Tags: nginx

I want only www.mydomain.com, 121.121.121, anything else should redirect to www.mydomain.com.

Why: I need to send everything to www.mydomain.com because we have had people setting up other domains (www.otherdomain.com) pointing to our IP address, so it acts like a mirror of our site. We don't know why they do this but Google starts crawling their site as if it was a different site entirely and it causes trouble. I need to allow the server's IP addresses through because we use that for internal server chatter via a custom API, to get around the load balancer.

Comment: I am a bit unclear about what exactly you are trying to do - could you give a bit more detail (and/or clarify a little what your issue is)? Do you have a log entry showing the kind of traffic you mean (i.e. a hit/redirect to www.otherdomain.com)? What is your current config looking like?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ambiguous, and you have't included your Nginx/server configurations. Please edit your question to include them if this doesn't answer your question.

I think you're asking how to serve your content only via your actual website, and not allow other domains pointed at your server to serve your content. However you've used the word redirect, which makes me wonder if you want to redirect people browsing on these other domains to the main domain.

In practice, you probably can't completely stop this. People could just crawl your site and post up a copy. You can make it more difficult though. Something like this

```
# Existing server block
server {
  server_name www.example.com;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  location / {
    # whatever
  }
}

# Existing server block to redirect http to https
server {
  server_name www.example.com example.com;
  listen 80;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

# Existing server block to redirect https root domain to https wwww
server {
  server_name example.com;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

# New server block
server {
  server_name _;
  # Next two lines say listen http/https for all other domains than example.com
  listen 443 ssl http2 default server; 
  listen 80 default server;

  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```